# Can a 300W kitchen aid do meat grinding?

Tags: stand-mixer

I have a kitchen aid artisan with 300W and have read conflicting opinions on what it can and can't do. Many seem to have a hard time using meat grinder and food processor attachments, because of the low power.
Is this the case, or does it simply take longer or require more prep (precutting the meat into smaller pieces for example)? What kind of meat would it have problems with? Why would it have issues with a food processor, which only cuts relatively soft vegatables?

Answer (score 1):

Kitchenaid mixers can grind meat, I know because I have one with the meat grinder attachment and I've used it do just that, as well as make sausages. The problem is one of expectation: it is not the biggest or the fastest meat grinder, if you are going to grind meat often and in large quantities a purpose built one is a better choice for you as it will be faster. However, if you don't need to grind often the kitchenaid one is a compact, effective and relatively cheap solution. It helps to cut the meat into manageable chunks that will fit down the throat.

Comment: How much watt does yours have? Will it work with 300W?

Comment: Yes, it will work with a 300W one @user1721135.

Answer (score 1):

I generally agree with @GdD.  I use my kitchenaid as my only meat grinder, and regularly grind up to 5 - 10 pounds of meat for sausage and salumi making. I do have some tips to improve the experience.  First, do not purchase the plastic Kitchenaid grinder attachment.  Instead, purchase an all metal one.  I believe Chefs Choice makes one.  There might be others.  This makes a big difference.  First, there is less movement in the parts.  Second, you can get it very cold by placing the parts in the freezer before use.  This leads to my second tip, (and this is true regardless of grinder) which is to par-freeze your meat after you cut it into strips that will easily fall into the feed tube of the grinder.

In other news: I don't have, or use, the food processor attachment.  I have used the pasta extruder (it sucks), but the pasta roller is a fantastic improvement over my hand roller.

Comment: How much watt does yours have? Does the par freezing help hygiene or does it help the grinder? Same with cooling the grinder, it is done for hygienic purposes correct?

Comment: Par-freezing is to keep the fat from melting/smearing, not so much hygiene or mechanical cooling. It is ultimately for product quality. This is particularly important in grinding processes that take longer.  Work as cold as possible. I have KitchenAid Artisan, says "max watts 325" on the side.